# iOS: React Native: In-App Purchase: Receipt Verification

Tags: ios, react-native, in-app-purchase

I'm using [react-native-in-app-utils](https://github.com/chirag04/react-native-in-app-utils) to facilitate an In-App purchase. My question in regarding receipts and their verification on the backend.

Based on the documentation, one can query for `receiptData` without a `transactionId` but I've noticed that `receiptData` changes after a transaction is made.

I'm wondering what is a reliable way to get a receipt for a particular transaction and what data to store in my database so that I can verify the receipt and the transaction via a daily cron job?

Answer (score 1):

`react-native-in-app-utils` was recently updated to provide a `transactionReceipt` which solves this problem.